# Set Date and Time in Different Field in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java

I am inserting Date Object from Java to Mongodb,
mongo ISODate(...) stores Date with Time,
my requirement is to Store both in different field.

is this possible ?

**note** : don't want solution that stores milliseconds instead of date.
want to store only date like "2013-06-19" and time like "00:00:00"

if i use String format for this than hard to perform date operation.

Comment: DB db =  mongo.getDB("demo");
DBCollection dbCollection = db.getCollection("testcoll");
Date date = new Date();
dbCollection.save(new BasicDBObject("date", date));

Comment: No, MongoDb doesn't have a "date only" or "time only" field. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-bson Consider just storing a date value as a `Date` instance without the time and the time as an integer.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the Date object to unix timestamp as `timestamp`, then store `timestamp / 86400` to a field and `timestamp % 86400` to another field.

Comment: after inserting , Mongo Object looks like {"date": ISODate("2013-06-09"),"Time": "00:02:00"} ?

Comment: @yogeshprajapati convert the date to 1370707320, calc the date 1370707320 / 86400 = 57720 and the time 1370707320 % 86400 = 57720. and then store them into mongodb: `{"date": 15864, "time": 57720}`

Comment: i know but i want same as given above, Note is written in my question.